# I am receiving a Type Error: int not callable when writing a method within a class which has no reserved words, or missing math operators

Tags: python, class, methods, typeerror

I am writing a class ExerciseSession which pulls in the duration, and intensity, and then returns the calories burned in a method within. With an additional setter, the code runs properly with the initial call, but when the data is changed, it returns a Type Error - int not callable, after the setter updates the data. I'm not sure what's wrong - when I've debugged it line by line, it is changing the data properly, so the code should run. Since it DOES run the first time, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Here are my setter details:

```
def set_exercise(self, new_name):
    self.name = new_name
    
def set_intensity(self, new_intensity):
    self.intensity = new_intensity
    
def set_duration(self, new_duration):
    self.duration = new_duration 
    

def calories_burned(self):
    self.calories_burned = 0
    
    if self.intensity == "Low":
        self.calories_burned = str(4 * self.duration)
    
    elif self.intensity == "Medium":
        self.calories_burned = str(8 * self.duration)
    
    elif self.intensity == "High":
        self.calories_burned = str(12 * self.duration)       
    
    return self.calories_burned
```

Again - when you call a print on a change to an instance, that's when it returns the error, even though it successfully changes the data.

I've reordered, defined the calories burned in the constructor, and even set a setter for calories burned, but the error remains the same. As you can see I've even tried changing the type - but then I get the Type error - str object not callable...

Comment: Please include the exact and complete error message with traceback.

Comment: Do you intend `self.calories_burned` to be a string or an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is right here:

```
def calories_burned(self):
    self.calories_burned = 0
```

You've defined a function named `calories_burned`, but after you run it the first time, it shadows itself by defining an instance variable with the same name. If you try calling the method a second time, you'll instead be trying to call the integer, which gives you the error you describe.

Pick a different name for either the method or the attribute. A leading underscore is sometimes a popular way to name internally used attributes: `self._calories_burned`. Or, since the attribute doesn't appear to be used anywhere outside of the method body, you might consider getting rid of the attribute all together, and just using a local variable to do the calculations on: `calories_burned`, rather than `self.calories_burned`. It's also a bit suspect that you're using the same variable name for both an integer, and a string later on. Python doesn't *require* you to bind only a single type to a given name, but it's usually good design to do so, if only so that you always know what type it contains without any ambiguity.

Comment: GENIUS! Thank you, that was it. I didn't realize I was basically looping back on my function by the name I gave the instance. This is a good lesson for me. I appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 0):

"Type error - str object not callable..." might mean that you have overridden the "str" function in the code preceding this code snippet. Can you try to `print(str)` or `print(int)` and let us know what it says? If you append whole code it might also be easier to find the problem. I did not notice any problem with the code snippet you shared here.

Comment: I appreciate the answer- it turned out I was causing the error by using the same name for the function and the instance, once I changed it - it ran perfectly.